# Call method of base class from derived class object python

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance

I have two class and methods having same name .I have the object of derived class. When i call the method (foo) from derived class object it should call the base class method.

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print "A Foo"

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print "B Foo"

b = B()
b.foo() # "B Foo"
```

After doing some search i got some solution as below and not sure whether it is proper way of doing it or not

```
a = A()
b.__class__.__bases__[0].foo(a) # A Foo
```

Is there any better way of doing it.

Comment: You should upgrade to Python 3. If you must use Python 2, `A` should inherit from `object` to make it a new-style class (where *"new"* means Python 2.2 and up, or about 17 years old!), then you can use `super`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 3, use `super`:

```
class A:
    def talk(self):
        print('Hi from A-land!')

class B(A):
    def talk(self):
        print('Hello from B-land!')

    def pass_message(self):
        super().talk()

b = B()
b.talk()
b.pass_message()
```

Output:

```
Hello from B-land!
Hi from A-land!
```

You can do the same thing in Python 2 if you inherit from `object` and specify the parameters of `super`:

```
class B(A):
    def talk(self):
        print('Hello from B-land!')

    def pass_message(self):
        super(B, self).talk()

b = B()
b.talk()
b.pass_message()
```

Output:

```
Hello from B-land!
Hi from A-land!
```

You can also call the method as if it were a free function:

```
A.talk(b)
B.talk(b)  # the same as b.talk()
```

Output:

```
Hi from A-land!
Hello from B-land!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have multiple methods in the derived class and base class with the same name. Based on scenario i need to call the methods of A or B.

Comment: @Gopi: That sounds like you picked a bad design and you should redesign it.

Comment: @user2357112 you are correct. Working with legacy. :(

Comment: @Gopi How does that relate to my answer?

Comment: @gmds What i meant here is that i have multiple methods overridden in the child class. I cannot create methods like `pass_message` for all to call the base class methods.

Comment: @Gopi Then use the third suggestion...?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method (foo) from derived class object, it won't call the base class method, because you're **overriding** it. You can use another method name for your base class or derived class to solve the interference.